# what similar command of fread in c#

Tags: c#, c++, file, pointers, programming-languages

I read this commands in c++ language

```
FILE * fp;
BYTE r,g,b;
fp=fopen(fn,"rb");
fread((BYTE * )&b,sizeof(BYTE),1,fp);
```

I am Bigeneer in c# ,what is similar commands in c# langugehow can I use pointer `(BYTE * )&b` in c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0bs3w9t.aspx) object for File operations and for opening the file you can use [File.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of fOpen

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for all lines :

```
using system.IO;

string[] mylines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"myfile.txt");
```

Or this for one line :

```
  string mytext = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"myfile.txt");
```